# Consuming Both of Text/plain and Application/json with JAX-RS?

Tags: java, jax-rs

I have the following method in my webservice that only accepts text/plain:

```
        @PUT
        @Path("/{resourceName}")
        @Produces("text/plain")
        @Consumes("text/plain")
       public String putResources(...){
        ...
     }
```

What I would to do is to change it in a way so as to accept json parameters as well. Is it possible?

Comment: what is the version of jax-rs you are using?

Comment: Thank you for your time. The version I'm using is 2.5.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to support both, You have to use like this.

```
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN })
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN })
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it and let you know how it went.

Comment: Thanks that's what I was looking for.